# Contacting a professor of an ancient language I translated poems to

Tags: etiquette, communication

I am a high school sophomore and have been studying Sanskrit for 6 years. Recently I started studying Pali (similar to Sanskrit) and translated some classical English poems.

I am in India, and luckily there are many professors of Pali in universities here. Considering how there are barely any instructors available, I was wondering if I could write to the professors about these poems. I have a few questions:

1. If I request them to go through the poems, and advise me about the grammar, etc., how would I word the email? Would an introduction followed by the poems and request for advice be okay?
2. Up to what extent is it acceptable for me to ask them for help (I don't want it to be like I am taking tuitions from them or using them as translators)?
3. Is there anything else I should be aware of while contacting them?

Thank you.

Answer (score 12):

It may not be a good idea to send the translations upfront; rather try to email them about your interest and seek their advice on how to proceed. Seek their permission to share your work; don't assume it beforehand.

There is a good chance that some of them will appreciate the interest and respond favorably. The extent of their support is entirely upto them, and it is best to let them propose it. Once they respond, you will have a better idea on how to proceed.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Find out if there are some societies , organizations or literary groups working in Pali. You may get to know some writers or poets. These people are very dedicated to the promotion of the language. Make someone highly capable as your Ustad as is done in music or other trades and request him to guide you. Take part in literary activities of Pali.

Professors are helpful but mostly to the students in their class. External students are not encouraged.